# Error caracteres en utf8

Tags: php, utf-8, codificación

Tengo una web en portugues, en la que al cambiar la versión de `php` y alguna cosa mas, al insertar en base de daos lo hace mal y al recuperarlo sale de la siguiente forma:

```
O hotel dispÃµe de 150 quartos. Todos os quartos tÃªm telefone de ligaÃ§Ã£o directa, acesso
```

Como se puede ver, estos caracteres: `Ã§Ã£` no son los correctos.

El caso es que si aplico a ese texto un `utf8_encode()` queda de la siguiente forma:

```
O hotel dispÃµe de 150 quartos. Todos os quartos tÃªm telefone de ligaÃ§Ã£o directa, acesso
```

Sigue saliendo igual.

Pero si aplico un `utf8_encode(utf8_decode())` sale correcto:

```
O hotel dispõe de 150 quartos. Todos os quartos têm telefone de ligação directa, acesso
```

El problema esque hay algunos casos en que con `utf8_encode()` sale bien y otros no, y también sin poner nada aparece correcto. Como puedo detectar automaticamente cuando debo usar uno u otro?

Actualmente lo tengo puesto manualmente con `if - else` en función del `id` de la página, pero cada vez hay mas por lo que necesito automatizarlo

Comment: Los textos los tienes directamente en ficheros? Base de datos? Mira que codificación tienen los ficheros y/o la conexión a la base de datos. Si están e nbase de datos en que codificación esta la base de datos y/o las tablas.

Comment: Están en base de datos, el problema es al hacer el insert. Pero ahora no puedo cambiar los cientos de registros que estan mal en la base de datos. Por eso modifico solo la vista @Christian

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que la conexión a la base de datos la estés haciendo con una codificación diferente a UTF-8

Comment: Probe con varias, el problema es que como en la bbdd hay algunos datos bien codificados y otros no pues puse `utf8` que era la que menos errores me daba @Christian

Comment: Podrías probar con http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: ¿Has comprobado la codificación del archivo php? ¿UTF-8 sin BOM?

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises el problema **en el orden explicado en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967)** a la pregunta [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/29967), **para que te evites codificar-decodificar innecesariamente**.

Comment: Lo mirare, ese caracter, también me aparece a mi a veces @A.Cedano

Comment: Lo probare, gracias @Christian

Answer (score -1):

¿Que motor de base de datos está usando? Si usa MySql intente agregar después de declarar la conexión a la base de datos mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8'); o mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link), dependiendo la extensión que este usando, esto le garantizará que en cada conexión almacenará o recuperará los registros adecuadamente además puede dejar la codificación de la base de datos así: database charset=utf8 y database collation utf8_general_ci